# Can't terminate the thread using pthread_exit

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I cant terminate the thread, it keeps sending things even after I close the terminal...

```
void *RTPfun(void * client_addr);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t RTPthread;
   pthread_create(&RTPthread, NULL, &RTPfun, (void*)client_addr);
   ...
   ...   
   pthread_exit(&RTPfun);
   return 0;
 }

 void *RTPfun(void * client_addr)
 {
     ...
     ...
     return 0;
 }
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`pthread_exit` kills your current thread.

Notice, that if you kill the main thread as you do, it does not terminate the process. Other threads keep running.

You probably want to use `pthread_cancel`.

More generally though, killing threads is a bad idea. Correct way is to ask your threads politely to terminate and wait till they do.

Comment: I tried  pthread_cancel(RTPthread); from the main and the RTP thread keeps working.. the main() comes to its end, ad the thread keeps running...

Comment: You need to read http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html and understand cancellation type.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `exit()` from main, it will terminate main thread with all other thread.

If you call the method `pthread_exit()` from your main it will terminate main thread and let other thread will run continuously.

In your case you are calling pthread_exit() from main so your main thread get terminated, and other thread running until thread gets finish the job.

To cancel thread Add Below in RTPfun and add pthread_cancel in main.

> /* call this when you are not ready to cancel the thread */
>        pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, NULL);
>
> /* call this when you are ready to cancel the thread */
>       pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);

Working sample code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void *RTPfun(void * client_addr);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t RTPthread;
    int client_addr;
   pthread_create(&RTPthread, NULL, &RTPfun, (void*)client_addr);
   sleep(2);

   pthread_cancel(RTPthread);
   pthread_join(RTPthread, NULL);

   return 0;
 }

 void *RTPfun(void * client_addr)
 {
    int count = 0;
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, NULL);
    while(1) {
        if(count > 10) {
                printf("thread set for cancel\n");
                pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);     
        }
        sleep(1);
        printf("count:%d\n", count);
        count ++;
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Used `sleep` in code for just understanding.

Comment: the main() souldn't wait until the RTP thread is finished, because they are not depends on each other. the RTP just sends video, I need to make the RTP terminate my main().. and then exit the main()..

Comment: ok, I think this is not the problem- inside the RTP thread, im launchnig "gst-launch", im using it to transmit video from the camera to another client. the pthread_cancel, cancel the thread, but it will not shut down the "gst-launch" and the camera keeps running and transmitting. I need to hit "ctrl-c" via c programming. I tried system( ^C) and system(ctrl-c) but without success.....

Comment: @user1673206 use `raise(SIGINT)` in c program to hit ctrl+c.

Comment: I tried it. the camera keeps sending data :/ anyway- right after the pthread_cancel(RTPthread); it gives me error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @user1673206 Add `pthread_exit(0)` in thread handler, where you want to close the thread.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding:

From  "man pthread_exit" clearly talks about the description and rational behavior.

we will need to clean-up all respected resource that  are been used in the thread created. 
 " The pthread_exit() function shall terminate the calling thread and make the value value_ptr available to any successful join with the terminating thread."

we shall pass "value_ptr" to exit(value_ptr) --> this will help to analyse what was the results of exit process.

obviously exit() - call exiting from the process, will release resources that used for.

In other way, you can create pthread in detached state, this attribute will reclaim the resources implicitly when pthread_exit . Refer "man pthread_detach".

We don't need to use pthread_join .. either go for pthread_detach again its simple go ahead set attribute .

/* set the thread detach state */
ret = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&tattr,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

Thanks.
Sankar

Answer (score 0):

Your `pthread_exit()` exits the current thread. The [parameter is used to pass a return value](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_exit) to any thread that then wants to join with it - and not to specify which thread to exit, as your code is implying.

The nicest way to do what you want is to use [`pthread_cancel()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cancel) from your main thread. It takes the thread to cancel as a parameter, and then sends a cancellation request to that thread. Notice though, that by default cancellation is deferred, so your thread will keep on running until it hits a function that is a [cancellation point](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_09.html#tag_02_09_05) - if you don't use any of those functions, you can insert an explicit cancellation point with a call to `pthread_testcancel()`.

If you need to do some cleanup (for instance to `free` allocated memory, unlock mutexes, etc), you can insert a cleanup handler that is automatically called when canceling the thread. Have a look at [`pthread_cleanup_push()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cleanup_push) for this.

You can also set your thread to use asynchronous cancellation - your thread can then be canceled immediately, without hitting a cancellation point. However, asynchronous cancellation should only be used if you aren't using any system calls at all (that is, it's okay if you're purely doing calculations on already available data - but not if you're for instance using `printf`, file I/O, socket communication or similar), as otherwise you'll risk your system ending up in an inconsistent state.

After calling `pthread_cancel()`, your main thread should call [`pthread_join()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join) on the canceled thread, to make sure all thread resources are cleaned up (unless you create the thread as detached).

You can of course also just have a shared `doExit` flag between the two threads, that the main thread can set, and which the other thread looks at from time to time. It's basically a manual way of using `pthread_cancel()`.